# "Application" + "when using something"

Tags: phrase-usage, clauses

> Exemplary applications when using functional sliders that can be used in many ways

Is it correct? I've got problems mainly with the connection "application" and "when using".

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a complete sentence. You have given a noun phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Besides grammar, you'll also want to keep an eye on style.  When you see repetition, such as *using ... used* in one sentence, that's a sign it's probably time for a rewrite!

How about *Let's consider some sample applications of functional sliders*?

By the way, *when using* is a nice construction that can sometimes work well.  For example, *Care must be taken with this approach when using functional sliders as the main design feature.*  (I made that up.  I don't know what *functional sliders* are.)

Frankly, the sentence fragment you wrote sounds like you're trying to translate from your main language, in a word-for-word sort of way.  Generally, one can get better results by googling the vocabulary you're interested in using, and the construction.  Other people's sentences will show you authentic vocabulary and constructions used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the usage of the word 'applications'.

On the assumption that it is being used to denote a number of uses for an item, that part of the sentence appears to be fine. However, as a whole it appears to be poorly constructed and repetitive, the applications you are referring to, are they of the functional sliders? The sentence doesn't appear to be complete, I would rephrase as follows:

> It has exemplary applications when used with functional sliders which
>   can be used in many ways.

Comment: Exemplary applications when using functional sliders that can be used in many ways:

Comment: "Exemplary applications when using functional sliders that can be used in many ways" : to record what time you fed your baby, to keep track which breast was last used and so on. And I list exemplary applications in turn. Then is it correct or poor constructed and should be like your example?

Comment: and the word "use" is used twice and it sounds strange

Comment: That's true, I forgot to address that point. Couldn't you say: "Functional sliders are versatile and have many exemplary applications"?

Answer (score 0):

Functional sliders can be used in many ways. Some examples of applications:  {list...,...,}